# What's the recommended API to use for querying Conversations for Google Groups?

Tags: google-api, gmail-api, google-workspace, google-groups-api

According to [Get Google Group emails with Gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857925/get-google-group-emails-with-gmail-api) (and threads far in the past), there wasn't any main method to support querying conversations directly for Google Groups within a domain after listing existing Google Groups (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/list). Has this changed, or is the recommended method still to:

- List the existing groups via the Directory API above
- Query emails for messages with filter "to:<google_group>"

To my knowledge, this also doesn't cover a variety of edge cases, such as Google Group Conversations that may have been deleted from inboxes, tracking emails sent to the Google Group that might have failed the send (from message not being approved or sender not having permissions), etc.

Comment: It hasn't changed. Recently I was in the need of querying the last time an email was sent to a group. So I had to made a ridiculous process in order to get the maximum accuracy possible.

Comment: @Morfinismo I have recently been assigned this same task, would you be willing to share your ridiculous process so that I can compare it to my ridiculous process?

Comment: @Jensen010 Well, if you organization has google vault, then it's easier because you just have to search for the last email sent to a group. Otherwise, it gets really complicated.

Comment: @Oh! I didn't even think of that! Did you end up using the vault API to automate something or did you just look manually? If manual, I'm all for it at this point, just want this project done