# What permissions changes do I need in order to generate a token for a Google Group?

Tags: request, authorization, gmail-api, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm trying to make a request to get messages from a Google Group, but the token request that works for getting messages from a User does not work for a Group, indicating that there is some change I need to make to the Group itself potentially. What needs to be done in order to do that? I see that it's [possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51857925/get-google-group-emails-with-gmail-api) but what needs to be done in order to get a credential for this request?

Comment: As of now there is no way to directly gather messages from a group as going through [all Google groups api methods](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups) there does not seem to be one to access the emails, on the example you provided they work around this by reading the messages of a user who is part of that group, since group members typically receive the emails sent to groups, you should be able to get emails sent to a group form the inbox of one of it's members

Comment: By the way if you happen to have a code sample we could definitely provide more insight! if you could, please share a code sample.